# How to resolve it "RangeError (index): Invalid value : Valid value range is empty : 0" in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, error-handling, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I'm to trying to get images from firestore database and put onto String type list and want to show as the slider Image.
but the above error is occurring on Screen but after milliseconds, error goes and images show as slider

**Decleared Global Varible:**

```
 List<String> getSliderImages=[];
```

**Method for fetched images from firestore:**

And this method is calling inside `initState()` method

```
 void getSliderImage(){
   List<String> userId=[];
    Firestore.instance.collection("Slider").getDocuments()
    .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f){
        setState(() {
         userId.add(f.documentID);  
        });
      });


      for(int i=0;i<userId.length;i++){
        setState(() {
         print('snap.documentID_IF_userId :${userId[i]}');
         Firestore.instance.collection('Slider').document(userId[i]).get().then((DocumentSnapshot document){
          String image=document['Image'];
          getSliderImages.add(image); 
          print('snap.documentID_IF_userId_IMAGE :$image');
          print("getSliderImages:$getSliderImages");
         });
        });
      } 
    }).catchError((onError){
      print(onError); 
      setState(() {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "$onError"); 
      });
    });
  }
```

**Slider widget, there I want to display images:**

Here I used [carousel_pro](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_pro) plugin for Slider

```
Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                //color: Colors.black
              ),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
              child: Carousel(
                images: [
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[0]),
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[1]),
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[2]),
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[3]),

                  ],//getSliderUserId
                showIndicator: true,
                borderRadius: true,

                moveIndicatorFromBottom: 100.0,
               noRadiusForIndicator: false,
                overlayShadow: false,
               overlayShadowColors: Colors.white,
                overlayShadowSize: 0.7,
             )
            ),
```

Comment: Can you please try with  SizedBox.expand(child: new Carousel())

Comment: But I'm confused, what's the relation of  `SizedBox.expand` with index.

Comment: By the way, I tried, according to you but still occurring  same error.

Comment: Try with container fix height and width

Comment: I don't think, this error is occurring by widget.  
I think , during getting image data from firestore , it takes some millisecond and meanwhile widget gets call.

Comment: Then add 0 size image array over there and update state when you get your data

Comment: I didn't understand, Could you please explain to me with code. 
or where I've to change???

Comment: Yup sure, can you post whole code that you have tried for this functionality. But firebase create problem for me

Comment: I cannot post whole code.
I've posted as the need for this error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved it by myself,
this error was occurring because of `getSliderUserId[]` was empty at initially.
so, I put a condition on the widget. if `getSliderImages.isEmpty` then show progress indicator otherwise Display Slider Image.

Now it's working perfectly without getting indexing error :)

**Here Modified code:**

```
Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0)),
                //color: Colors.black
              ),
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/5,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
              child:  getSliderImages.isEmpty? 
              CircularProgressIndicator()
               :
              Carousel(
                images: [
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[0]),
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[1]),
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[2]),
                   new NetworkImage(getSliderImages[3]),
                  ],
               showIndicator: true,
               borderRadius: true,
               moveIndicatorFromBottom: 100.0,
               noRadiusForIndicator: false,
               overlayShadow: false,
               overlayShadowColors: Colors.transparent,
               overlayShadowSize: 0.7,
             )
            ),
```