# Does this stream work the way I imagine it would?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-test

I have a bug in my app that could be caused by several things. To share the whole problem would be too much, so I am dividing the questions into individual areas that might cause the problem.
One area that could cause the problem is this:

---

I have created a stream that should returns the blue underlined number.

[image]

Therefore, I use this stream:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStufe() {
    var stufe = userTodos.where('Stufe', isEqualTo: 1);
    stufe = stufe.where('userID', isEqualTo: userID);
    return stufe.snapshots();
  }
```

Does this stream work the way I imagine it would?

Comment: What is the error that you’re facing?

Comment: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0` And one cause could be that the stream returns nothing...

Comment: Check out these links once: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58246309/how-to-resolve-it-rangeerror-index-invalid-value-valid-value-range-is-empt) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470331/rangeerror-index-invalid-value-valid-value-range-is-empty-0-error-flutter)

Comment: Thanks, but I still need ti know, if the stream returns a value?

Comment: Can you try printing the returned value from the `getStufe()` function by calling the function?